# is there a way to use a gradle variable in Java class

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I am part of a team that works on an Android app that uses a RESTful api(using [retrofit](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client) 1.9), and we are looking for ways to set up a config file, so that we wouldn't have to change the connection string(API URL) from the live server to our own dev environment, any time that we want to add or change something in the app.

Is there a way to use Gradle for this? in other words, is there a way for us to create a gradle config, in which we declare a variable and use that variable in the project(the API URL)?

what other options do we have?

Just as a side note, This is the first Android project that we are doing, So I apologize upfront if this is not a very good question(any hints on improvement would be appreciated).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can use the `build types` for that to add a `buildConfigField`, which will then be available in `BuildConfig.[variableName]`.

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        buildConfigField "String", "API_URL", "[apiURL]"
        buildConfigField "Boolean", "DEBUG_MODE", "true"
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        buildConfigField "String", "API_URL", "[apiURL]"
        buildConfigField "Boolean", "DEBUG_MODE", "false"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
```

Comment: tell me if I understand this correctly, each developer would have their own buildType and in hte buildType you define your `API_URL`?

Comment: No, you would create a build type for each backendsystem you have. One BuildType (e.g. debug) for developing against your dev environment and maybe one for you staging environment and finally one for your release environment. The developers can choose which buildType they want to use in Android Studio. Check View -> Tool Windows -> Build Variants.

Comment: @Renier and you access it any where by using `BuildConfig.API_URL`