# development and production version of one app

Tags: android, git, version-control

I develop an app with Android Studio and I want to create different versions of the app.

1. Development version should always use the test website www.aaaaaaaaa.com
2. Production version should use the release website www.bbbbbbbb.com

I made two git-branches and tried to use the same properties-file with different URIs. But each time when I commit it or merge my branches URIs are unified.

May be I can use gradel settings somehow or you can give me another peice of advice how can I user different URI for different branches and not to rewrite them each time after commit and merge.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35356707/3134215

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Gradle Build types for this kind of task. See http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html for more information.

Add something like the following to your build.gradle file:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "URL", "www.aaaaaaaaa.com"
    }
    release {
        buildConfigField "String", "URL", "www.bbbbbbbbb.com"
    }
    println "Applied basic configurations."
}
```

You can access this field via `BuildConfig.URL` in the JavaCode of your app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make following changes within your gradle:

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```